# Creating table layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a php file called search.php. I want to show the result on a table

I want a table structure like this.

```
 __________________________
|        |________________|
|        |________________|
|        |________________|
|________|________________|  
         |________________|
         |________________|
```

On the left side I want to place a picture which will be obtained from database and to the right I will place information about the student photo.

Could you write a code. Can we separate photo and the information column by a vertical line only.(if yes,HOW ?? )

Comment: *"Could you write a code..."* – **A:** no. Tell us what you tried and how much time you spent searching. Plus show us what you already have code-wise. *"if yes,HOW ??"* – **A:** HTML/CSS, trying something perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" style="border-right: 1px solid black">
      <img src"whatever.png" alt="" />img
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>      
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>      
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>6</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

but really: learn html an get used to the boxed model, that is: use `div`s

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php  

    $sql = "Select FROM * `yourtablename` where `id` = 'theidofthestudent'";
    if(!mysql_query($sql)){
       die(mysql_error());
    } else {
       echo "<table border="1px" style="text-align:center;" align="justify">";
       echo "<th>Photo of student</th>";
       echo "<th>Name of the student</th>";
       echo "<th>Student Detials</th>";

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style="float:left;">' . $row['student_pic'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td style="float:right;">' . $row['student_name'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td style="float:right;">' . $row['student_details'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"
       } echo "</table>";
    }
  ?>
```